# Is there a way in R to insert a bar graph into a table?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot figure out how to insert a graph into my table such that each row of my graph aligns with each row of my table.

Here is an example of some data to play with:

```
library(survival)
df <- data.frame(futime = abs(rnorm(1000, mean = 5, sd = 5)),
                 outcome = sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 1000),
                 variable1 = factor(sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 1000)))
fit.coxph <- coxph(Surv(time = futime, event = outcome) ~ variable1, data = df)
```

I am trying to achieve something like the figure created by `ggforest`.

```
ggforest(fit.coxph)
```

[image]

The reason I don't want to use `ggforest` is because I want to do further customisation of the figure. I can already create the graph (code below), I'm just trying to work out how to insert this into a table.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = "Variable 1",
                  Ratio = exp(coef(fit.coxph)),
                  CI = exp(confint(fit.coxph)))
ggplot(df1, 
       aes(x = rownames(df1), y = Ratio, ymin = CI.2.5.., ymax = CI.97.5..)) +
  geom_pointrange() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous((trans = "log2")) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.2) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: What customisations do you intend to do? Generally speaking, aligning a table next to a ggplot object isn't trivial, & other options may be simpler. In the case of `ggforest()`, while the function returns a grob object, the conversion from ggplot to grob happens right at the end of the function. You may find it easier to modify that function to return the ggplot object instead, & make your modifications there.

Comment: @Z.Lin I hope to add a few extra columns, for information on sample size, number of positive outcomes and a short text comment on each variable. I just thought it would be neater in table format.
As a side note, if I find a method, I can also generalise it to make similar graphs for logistic regression models.

Comment: I think you'll have an easier time adding them as `geom_text` layers to your plot, at appropriate positions along the x-axis. But if you are set on creating separate tables, you can look into `gridExtra::grid.table` & the table combining functions from the `gtable` package.